# How to stop/play video which was dynamically added in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I am appending both `video` tag and it's controls via script. I am successful to bind `div` element but I am not able to play/stop video. Code given below:

```
$ad = $(".ayztd");
$ad.append($("<video controls='controls' id='ayztvideoplayer' autoplay><source src='" + data.ad.url + "' type='video/mp4'></video>"));
$ad.append('<div id="pbutton" class="player-buttons"></div>');

$(document).on( 'click','#pbutton', function()  {
    $('#ayztvideoplayer').paused 
        ? $('#ayztvideoplayer').play() 
        : $('#ayztvideoplayer').pause(); //Not working
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paused`, `play()` and `pause()` are properties and methods of the native `video` DOMElement, not the jQuery object. You need to retrieve the native element first before calling them. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click','#pbutton', function() {
    var player = $('#ayztvideoplayer')[0];
    player.paused ? player.play() : player.pause();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are appending the video tag after you have tried to set an even listener.
Try adding the event listener to as a call back just after you create the video node and its controls.

Its much easier in pure JS.

Comment: OP is using a delegated event handler bound to the `document` so this is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rory and Junior are both correct; a combined solution might look something like:

```
$ad = $(".ayztd");
$ad.append($("<video controls='controls' id='ayztvideoplayer' autoplay>    <source src='" + data.ad.url + "' type='video/mp4'></video>"));
$ad.append('<div id="pbutton" class="player-buttons"></div>');
bindVideoEventHandler();;

function bindVideoEventHandler() {
    $(document).on( 'click','#pbutton', function()  {
        var player = $('#ayztvideoplayer')[0];
        player.paused ? player.play() : player.pause();
    });
}
```

Also note that you're appending a video element to a div by class name, not id, so you may run into trouble if you later have two divs with class ayztd.